# Bitfinex API REST v2 - API invalid key

Tags: python, rest

I want to connect to the v2 Bitfinex REST API through Python, but I keep getting the error:

```
error 10100 apikey: invalid
```

However, when I use the same keys for v1, everything works fine. This is my Python code:

```
class MyTradeClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.URL = "{0:s}://{1:s}/{2:s}".format(PROTOCOL, HOST, VERSION)
        self.KEY = public
        self.SECRET = secret

    @property
    def _nonce(self):
        return str(int(time.time() * 100000))

    def _sign_payload(self, payload):
        j = json.dumps(payload)
        data = base64.standard_b64encode(j.encode('utf8'))

        h = hmac.new(self.SECRET.encode('utf8'), data, hashlib.sha384)
        signature = h.hexdigest()
        return {
            "X-BFX-APIKEY": self.KEY,
            "X-BFX-SIGNATURE": signature,
            "X-BFX-PAYLOAD": data
        }

    def wallets(self):
        payload = {
            "request": "/v2/auth/r/wallets",
            #"options": {"autoOpen": False}, # READ IT SOMEWHERE ON THE INTERNET, NOT SURE OF THE MEANING
            "nonce": self._nonce}
        signed_payload = self._sign_payload(payload)
        r = requests.post(self.URL + "/auth/r/wallets", headers=signed_payload, verify=True)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            return r.json()
        else:
            print('error, status_code = ', r.status_code)
            print(r.text)
            return ''
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your headers are wrong:

"bfx-nonce": nonce,"bfx-apikey": self.api, "bfx-signature": signature